# Search Text in specific view using solo.searchText

Tags: robotium

Assuming I have a ListView containing different elements and I want to search for a specific text in some of this List Elements - but not all of them.

Is there any chance to use `solo.searchText` only on specific views, or do I have to write my own function?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: tricky workarrounds - but im pretty sure it is not the way it is meant ;)